# Postpone a resume send request without losing a lead

Tags: resume, job-offer, networking

**Updated with more insight**

I've kept in touch with a senior manager in order to keep a lead for some job **in a year or so (just started a new one)**.

I emailed him recently to know things went on his side and expressed the fact that I'd be interested to join him **at some point**.

I think he might have misunderstood and proposed me in his last email to send him my resume as they are thinking of opening some roles in his company.

How would you **answer so I don't lose that lead?**
As I also **cannot update my resume quickly** (will take me a month), how would you tell him that I'd **need more time too to send it to him?**

Thank you!

Comment: It's typically good practice to ALWAYS have a resume ready, even if you have no intention of leaving. In practice that means updating your resume once every 6 months or so. That takes maybe an hour or so and is also helpful for your current job since it requires you to to look at yourself objectively . That's a good view point to have for salary discussion and career planning.

Comment: Also, it doesn't hurt to do an interview once in a while, just to network and for interview 'practice'. If the job isn't a great fit, you don't have to take it.

Comment: I just moved job. Updating a resume takes me hours, super tailored in my area

Comment: Why would it take a *month* to update a resume?

Comment: In short too busy these days and other priorities, won't be able to take time to work on this. Updating also requires hours. That person is very high profile so don't want to screw it up...

Comment: The idea that you need a month to update a resume comes off as patently ridiculous without further explanation. Not wanting to give us that explanation is understandable and your prerogative. Just know that answerers are going to have a hard time accepting such a constraint as a given and it also is hard to tailor an answer around such a constraint without specifics.

Comment: Making sense, though truth is that I can't take on more tasks. Doing my resume now will take me a lot of time as I changed my carrier radically 6 months ago and need to revamp everything. I don't want to screw up that resume update so the potential position, therefore requiring me time to update

Comment: Just updating you all: was able to send my resume only today, so took me 1.5 months. Had to revamp it and couldn't be faster as expected due to my work and personal load during the period. Your comments were of great help, thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hi Bob,
>
> Thanks for thinking of me.  I wasn't planning on looking for another year or so, but if the right opportunity comes along I'd be happy to discuss it.
>
> Please see my attached resume.
>
> Goul

Updating your resume doesn't take very much time. Sending Bob the resume invests a little bit in the networking relationship you have with him.  If this job doesn't work out, he may find another one for you later.

Who knows what may happen?  This could be a fantastic opportunity - more pay, more responsibility, more opportunity.  Don't be too quick to say 'no'.

I know you're not planning on switching jobs, but if they offered double what you're making now for a job that you know you could succeed at, would you turn it down?

Comment: To add to this: no-one knows what will have happened in a year. They may not be looking for people matching your skill-set any more, they may have forgotten about you, your contact may have moved on to another company, etc.

Comment: ... and there are also a whole bunch of factors that could change in your own life to make you not interested in moving come a year from now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated my question as it was missing some important background it seems. As for the resume update, it won't be fast on my side, minimum a month (not entering into the details of why)

Comment: I read your update.  Since you started the conversation and expressed interest in working there, that’s all the more reason to reply with a resume.

Comment: Agree. Issue is really about timing, ie. resume not ready and not ready to move. Your answer is nice though thanks. Just need to figure out how to bring the fact that I'll send the resume in few weeks

Answer (score 0):

I think one month for updating resume with Gov Federal Position is necessarily efficient. Because it is not simply updated as you update your biological information, surely, one updated resume is included with “ extension “ and “ showing your advanced improvement in works, fields that you are pursuing, that it maybe has tested, challenged, interacted and certified at various phases of  processing... is it a satisfied answer? Maybe, u will agree with me that , your future company will never mention “ update “or ... if you do not have anything “ interesting “ to up to date ! 
Sincerely, 
Kevin ( What is One day in life of an ISO means ..?)